# How do you write a custom jquery selector for all not shown fields excluding hidden fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to write a custom selector to select all fields that are returned by the :hidden selector except for the fields that are of type hidden.

Here's what I have.  It's breaking the page with no console error.

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
notShown: $(':hidden').not("hidden")
});
```

Comment: Do you mean an input of type 'hidden'?  If so you need .not('input:hidden')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(':hidden:not([type="hidden"])')
```

- [`hidden-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)
- [`not-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)
- [`attribute-equals-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

If you're only interested in form elements, add the [`input-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)  to the beginning of the selector.

```
$(':input:hidden:not([type="hidden"])')
```

Answer (score 0):

Every example of making a custom selector they do something like this:

$.expr[':'].notShown = function(obj) {
    return $(obj).not('input:hidden').is(':hidden');
}